# Moving existing PBIs to Features in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I've just upgraded TFS from 2012 to 2015. If I create a 'Feature' can I move PBIs under it so I can organise all of the PBIs into 'Features' and 'Epics'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can be answered by trying.

Comment: Rather than mess around with the current configuration, creating unnecessary work items for testing purposes, I'm building an identical environment to test.  However, I had hoped someone may already know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map a backlog item under a feature:

1. First choose Backlog items and **turn mapping on**.
2. Next, find the Unparented backlog items group.
3. Drag items that are currently unparented to the feature under which
   they belong.
4. Also, you can drag a backlog item to a different feature to change
   its parent.

[image]

Then you will see the dragged  PBI under the corresponding feature.

[image]

More detail info please refer this tutorial： [Map items to group them under a feature or epic](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/organize-backlog#map-items-to-group-them-under-a-feature-or-epic)

Comment: Many thanks for your response Patrick.  I will give this a try.